# conditional binding in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am really new to WPF and i was working on making a legend which has rectangles and information.
[Here is an example of the Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mKYX.png)

here is the xmal

```
        <ItemsControl Name="icColorInfo" ItemsSource="{Binding m_legendInfo}" 
                  BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="2,2,2,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="30" Fill="{Binding Color}"></Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Info}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The rectangle Fill binds to the color property of my legend class and
the textblock binds to the info property

Now what i want to do is, if the legend "Info" entry equals "Empty", i want the rectangle to have a dashed border (maybe set the Stroke property or something)

How can i bind to a specific item without affecting other items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple `DataTrigger` in the `ItemTemplate` can do that for you:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="2,2,2,2">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Height="25" Width="30" Fill="{Binding Color}" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Info}" />
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Info}" Value="">
        <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
        <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 2" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

You can adjust the stroke brush, thickness, and dash array until it looks right to you.  The stroke dash array is encoded as a sequence of pairs: the length of dash followed by the length of the space.  You can include as many as you like, but a single pair is all you need for a simple dashed or dotted pattern.

Note that you should generally not hard-code colors and brushes.  For `Stroke`, I'd recommend you use `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was trying to do something like that but i couldnt figure out how. Still new to this.
The solution u provided works for my needs. Thanks

Comment: Glad I was able to help :).  FYI, if you are satisfied with an answer on Stack Overflow, it is customary mark it as accepted (and upvote it, if you like) so that the responder is awarded reputation points.

Comment: Some nitpicking: The question asks for changing the Border if `Info` equals `"Empty"`, not an empty string `""`... although this may as well be what was actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need `Style.Triggers`

```
 <Style x:Key="RectangleStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Info}" Value="empty">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />                  
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Info}" Value="full">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> 
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And use above Style Trigger as follows

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"></Rectangle>
```

This will check `value` of `info` and sets Color accordingly.You might need to update a bit as above code is not tested. Hopefully this will be helpful.